# get inherited class using id and not knowing the class type

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a couple inherited classes from a base class.  My gsp lists the subclasses, so I know what the type of each class in the list.

tablePerHierarchy is false,  so I have one table that holds all inherited classes.

```
abstract class Base {
}

public class Sub1 extends Base {
}

public class Sub2 extends Base {
}
```

list.gsp:

```
<g:link action="show" id="${item.id}"/>
```

in my controller how can I get the correct Sub1/Sub2 instance if only the row id is known?

For example, here is what I don't want to do (2 queries):

```
Base.get(id)
```

figure out the class from the base, say its Sub2

get the real object:

```
Sub2.get(id)
```

Is there something like:

Here is the id, get me the fully derived class based on the id with one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. When you do `Base.get(id)`, GORM (with Hibernate) returns the real instance automatically which in this case is either of Sub1 or Sub2. You don't have to call `Sub1.get(id)` again.

If you want to check if the returned instance is of Sub1 or Sub2, you can do:

```
def instance = Base.get(id)
if (instance.instanceOf(Sub1))
  instance.doSub1Operation()
else if (instance.instanceOf(Sub2))
  instance.doSub2Operation
else
  throw new RuntimeException("Unknown instance type")
```